# how to get minimum date with exclude '0000-00-00' from mysql database into dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I want to retrieve date from database with exclude `0000-00-00` into dropdown list. I tried using `MIN()` function but it show the year from zero to current year.

```
<?php //year

    $earliest_year = "SELECT MIN(YEAR(appl_date)) FROM table WHERE YEAR(appl_date)> '0000-00-00'";
    $latest_year = date('Y'); 

?>

    <select name="year" style="width:60px;">
    <option value=""><?php echo $latest_year;?></option>

<?php 

    foreach ( range( $latest_year, $earliest_year ) as $year ) {
          $selected = ($year == 'year') ? 'selected' : '';
          echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$year.'">'.$year.'</option>';
                    } 

?> 
</select>
```

The expected result is to show the date from minimum to current year from database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT MIN(YEAR(appl_date)) FROM table WHERE appl_date > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT MIN(YEAR(appl_date)) FROM table WHERE YEAR(appl_date) IS NOT NULL
```